# Key binding to switch to specific application

Tags: key-bindings, functions, linux

I'm running Emacs in a GUI, and I like having a key binding that quickly switches me to a terminal. Yes, I know there's eshell, term, and shell in Emacs, but I still prefer a dedicated terminal emulator for a lot of my work.

When I'm on macOs, I use a function that switches application focus to iTerm,

```
(defun os-switch-to-term ()
  (interactive)
  (when (display-graphic-p)
    (do-applescript "tell application \"iTerm\" to activate")))
```

I'm pretty sure I lifted this from [doom-emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs). I'm now spending most of my time in Linux, so I'm searching for a way to translate the above functionality to something that will work in a different desktop environment (I'm currently using Gnome on Ubuntu, and gnome-terminal, though I'm still hunting for a terminal emulator I like better).

I imagine the options will depend on the flavor of Linux, and which window manager and/or desktop manager you're using, but as a start, how might I translate this to a Gnome environment w/gnome-terminal?

Comment: If you can call it from a terminal, and bring it to the front, then you can write your own using `start-process` or other shell-command function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```el
(defun os-switch-to-term ()
  "Open an external terminal window."
  (interactive)
  (unless (catch 'found
            (when (display-graphic-p)
              (cond
               ;; OSX
               ((and (eq system-type 'darwin)
                     (fboundp #'do-applescript))
                (do-applescript "tell application \"iTerm\" to activate")
                (throw 'found t))
               ;; GNU/Linux
               ((memq system-type '(gnu gnu/linux))
                (dolist (command '("gnome-terminal" "xterm"))
                  (when (executable-find command)
                    (start-process command nil command)
                    (throw 'found t)))))))
    ;; Fallback
    (call-interactively #'ansi-term)))
```

Comment: This will start a new instance of the terminal, [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) will switch to an existing one if it's installed and supported by the window manager